# How to remap a source table of a query to another table programmatically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on Oracle 11g. I get a user provided query e.g.

```
SELECT mycolumn
  FROM myschema.mytable
```

The query can be arbitrarily complex with subqueries and is not known in advance.
Now I want to change the query and redirect all usages of the source table `mytable` to another table `mytable_mod` no matter where in the query or subquery they occure.

Of course you can search the string for the occurrence of `mytable`, but this is a highly unreliable approach since other parts of the query may have the same name (a column for instance, or some comments)

I tried creating a view with that statement and use `DBMS_METADATA` to analyze it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYSCHEMA.TESTVIEW as 
SELECT mycolumn FROM myschema.mytable
```

With `DBMS_METADATA` you can replace the schema like this (after some preparation):

```
dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(handler, 'REMAP_SCHEMA', 
                             'MYSCHEMA', 'MY_OTHER_SCHEMA');
```

With `REMAP_NAME` instead of `REMAP_SCHEMA` you can replace the object name. But both methods only refer to the view name and not to the objects used inside the query of the view. So the result would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_OTHER_SCHEMA.TESTVIEW as 
SELECT mycolumn FROM myschema.mytable
```

Another idea is to output the create view statement as XML object. The I get all column definitions and the view name, but the query itself is just a text tag in the xml. My idea was to

1. extract the *query* as xml
2. replace the objects I want by looking at their tags
3. use `DBMS_METADATA.CONVERT` to convert the xml back to a ddl statement.

But as I said, the xml does not contain the sql query structure itself. Does someone know how to get an sql statement structured as an "xml object" or in some other structured form?

Comment: What is the technical reason to change QUERY? Why can't you change structure? Like, rename `myschema.mytable` to `myschema.mytable_old`, `create or replace view myschema.mytable as select * from myschema.mytable_mod`, and keep the query intact?

Comment: I understand what you're doing slightly better but the conditional aspect is still unclear; what sort of conditions are we talking about here?

Comment: I chanage the query, because the user should see that something changed. When the user refers to mytable he should always get the original mytable.

Comment: The `mytable_mod` is a view on `mytable` with some special filters.
The conditions are not so important. Basically the user can trigger the replace.
After a little more research I have the suspicion that there is no functionality to do that. I'm helping myself now with a little regexp gymnastics.

Comment: I would probably think about dynamically generating query in this case instead of its post-processing, but if that is not your option and the conditions are restrictive, then I guess you could take a look at `VPD` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#CIHHDHGD).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your conditions are but one method would be using [conditional compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS294); though this would mean you have to go through all your code it can be very useful in certain circumstances. It's not 100% clear whether this would help you; you start by mentioning "programmatically" but go on to say that you would want to search through strings, in which case it might.

Conditional compilation uses a set of static boolean statements to alter the source code at compilation. The compiler flags are prepended with `$$` and you control what happens with the construct `$IF-$THEN-$ELSE`.

For instance, if you wanted to change the table you select from your procedure might look something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure do_something (
  2       p_curs out sys_refcursor ) is
  3
  4  begin
  5
  6     $if $$right_schema $then
  7        open p_curs for
  8          select * from user_tables;
  9     $else
 10        open p_curs for
 11          select * from all_tables;
 12     $end
 13
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

If you look at the procedure using [`DBMS_METADATA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#i1015856) then it would look as it does above; however, [`DBMS_PREPROCESSOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_preproc.htm#CHDFHHJJ) you can see how it's been compiled:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_preprocessor.print_post_processed_source (
  3      object_type => 'PROCEDURE',
  4      schema_name => user,
  5      object_name => 'DO_SOMETHING');
  6  end;
  7  /
procedure do_something (
p_curs out sys_refcursor ) is
begin
open p_curs for
select * from all_tables;
end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is because the compiler flag, `$$right_schema` is, by default, false. Using the [ALTER PROCEDURE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_procedure.htm#LNPLS99997) statement we can set the flag to true:

```
alter procedure do_something compile plsql_ccflags = 'right_schema:TRUE';
```

Printing out the processed source now displays the following:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_preprocessor.print_post_processed_source (
  3      object_type => 'PROCEDURE',
  4      schema_name => user,
  5      object_name => 'DO_SOMETHING');
  6  end;
  7  /
procedure do_something (
p_curs out sys_refcursor ) is
begin
open p_curs for
select * from user_tables;
end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Oracle Base has [a useful article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2.php) with some examples as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your approach completely, but it seems I need to know the queries where I want to do the table remapping beforehand, which in my problem is not the case. I'll adjust the question to clarify.